# discord.py server template

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py

So I am trying to make a command that will create template, code:

```
@client.command()
async def template(ctx, name):
    await ctx.guild.create_template(name = name, description = None)
    await ctx.send('Done.')
```

Everytime when I use this command I got this error:

```
AttributeError: 'Guild' object has no attribute 'create_template'
```

Comment: The docs clearly state that `Guild.create_template` is new in version `1.7` which is not yet released.You can either wait till it's released or install it directly from github.

Comment: Thats the answer I was waiting for, thank you.

Answer (score -2):

1. You have wrote 'Guild' as 'guild'
2. Usage of `create_template`: `await discord.Guild.create_template(*, name, description=None)`
   (Just so you know)

Comment: That's not a problem, the [docs](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html?highlight=context#discord.ext.commands.Context.guild) clearly states that it is `guild` and not `Guild`.

Comment: No they aren't (https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Guild)

Comment: @MatanKa. what's the error? (Just one thing; it's NOT directly discord.Guild, it's for example ctx.guild!!)